# How to refresh a list widget data on a button click FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, api, dart, listview, flutter-listview

My flutter app displays bookings for a space, and the data comes from a rest api.

The screen has a vertical and horizontal list view.

The horizontal list view contains 14 buttons, with witch the user can decide what days bookings does he want to display on the vertical list view. The problem that I have is I cant refresh the vertical list views state with the button clicks to display the correct day.

Here is where I am currently:

The vertical List View:

```
Widget bookingListView(List data, BuildContext context) {
    if (data.isNotEmpty) {
        return Container(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: Scrollbar(
            showTrackOnHover: true,
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _horizontalScrollController,
            radius: Radius.circular(32),
            thickness: 5.0,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  controller: _horizontalScrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 6.0),
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                    Bookings booking = data[index];
                    String fromDate = booking.from;
                    String toDate = booking.to;

                    DateFormat inputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z');

                    DateTime fromD = inputFormat.parse(fromDate)
                        .toUtc()
                        .add(new Duration(hours: 2));
                    DateTime toD = inputFormat.parse(toDate).toUtc().add(
                        new Duration(hours: 2));

                    final frmDt = fromD.toLocal();
                    final toDt = toD.toLocal();

                    String from = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(frmDt);
                    String to = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(toDt);

                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Row(children: [
                              Text(
                                "$from",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 48.0,
                                    color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 6.0, right: 6.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  "-",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      fontSize: 48.0,
                                      color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "$to",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    fontSize: 48.0,
                                    color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
                              ),
                            ]),
                            subtitle: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                  .start,
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    booking.membership.name == null
                                        ? ""
                                        : booking.membership.name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: booking.membership.name == null
                                            ? 0
                                            : 40.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    booking.title == null
                                        ? ""
                                        : booking.title ,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize:
                                        booking.title  == null
                                            ? 0
                                            : 40.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                        color: Color(0xfff2f2f2)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          indent: 10.0,
                          endIndent: 10.0,
                          thickness: 0.2,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (data.isEmpty) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            heightFactor: 7,
            child: Text(
              "noBooking".tr().toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 46.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
```

And the horizontal List View:

```
Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                child: OutlinedButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    var from =
                                        "${formatFrom.format(DateTime.now())}";
                                    var to =
                                        "${formatTo.format(DateTime.now())} 23:59";

                                    String fromDate = from.toString();
                                    String toDate = to.toString();

                                    final SharedPreferences
                                        sharedPreferences =
                                        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                    sharedPreferences.setString(
                                        "from", fromDate);
                                    sharedPreferences.setString("to", toDate);

                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedIndex = 0;
                                      var format = new DateFormat('MM/dd');
                                      formattedDate =
                                          format.format(DateTime.now());
                                      print(selectedIndex);
                                      Network.getBookings();
                                    });

                                  },
                                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          26.0, 20.0, 26.0, 20.0),
                                      backgroundColor: selectedIndex == 0
                                          ? Color(0xfff78848)
                                          : Color(0x66404142),
                                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                    child: Text(dayOne.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 22.0)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

The remaining 13 button does the same as this one, just with different from and to datetime values.

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding new item to your list you have to locally add the item to you list  like  `list.add(newItem)` and then you have to call setState() which will rebuild your list and render the new item on your screen

Another solution : if you want to refreh the whole page then you can clear the previous list and toggle your loading variable and then call to your getDate() to get newly added data.

Comment: My data comes from an api call, i dont add data to the list locally

Comment: yes, you can... you are holding all the API responses in some local variable. so now you have all the data so you can do whatever you want to do with it

Answer (score 0):

with inserting data to list will be refresed.

```
setState(() {
  list.add(newItem); // or list.insert() can be used.
});
```

**Otherwise**, you can use button's `onTap:`/`onPressed:` with `setState(() {})`.

As like:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => setState(() {}),
  child: // widget what you want
),
```